# Можно ли восстановить исходники из data directory gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сервер с gitlab не запускается. Бэкапов нет.
Удалось достать с диска только папку /var/opt/gitlab
В ней есть директория с репозиториями var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories.

Структура папок в конкретном репозитории на картинке.

Можно ли как то из этой директории получить исходники проектов?

Comment: а покажите содержимое этого каталога (может внутренностей). Скорее всего там bare репозитории, а значит, их будет очень легко преобразовать в "нормальные" репозитории

Comment: Отредактируй вопрос и вставь туда эти данные. Ни черта не понятно же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как там есть все необходимые файлы, похоже, что это исправный bare репозиторий (то есть, репозиторий без рабочего каталога, обычное дело на "сервере"). Но можно как всегда это конвертнуть в "нормальный вид".

найдено здесь http://ibrahimsawalha.blogspot.com/2017/07/convert-bare-git-repository-into-normal.html и адаптировано.

- создайте каталог `.git`
- переместите туда все эти файлы и папки (`config`, `description`, `HEAD`, `objects` и другие).
- запустите `git config --local --bool core.bare false` собственно для конвертации.
- запустите `git reset --hard` или ручками сделайте checkout для нужных веток.

странно, я там не вижу каталога branches, где хранятся ветки. Но если что то пойдет не так - можно будет создать.

**ВНИМАНИЕ:** это как раз тот случай, когда лучше не запускать никакие GUI утилиты до полного восстановления репозитория. Так как не видно каталога branches, для этих утилит может быть выглядеть как репозиторий с удаленными ветками и они могут радостно предложить Вам "почистит мусор" (у меня так было). Также не запускайте `git gc` ручками.

**Также:** в любом случае сделайте копию репозитория (или того, что от него осталось) и поместите в надежное место (например, на внешний диск).

Comment: А можно ничего этого не делать, а просто рядом *клонировать* (`git clone --local ...`) из него в другой репозиторий. Или можно сделать *рабочее дерево* (`git worktree ...`)...

Comment: было бы хорошо, если бы Вы написали полные команды. Представьте человека, у которого вот так все накрылось и он не знает, что ему делать (а завтра здача проекта).

Comment: Это вам скорее к сведению, чтобы не заставляли людей делать какие-то очень сложные конструкции. А мне так лень... Кто-то всё равно должен читать документацию.

Comment: ну что ж поделаешь.